# Hide first Cell of UITableView on iPad

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView with various entries. Sometimes i need to scroll down, sometimes there are only a few entries, so everything is visible.

I want some settings and filters in my First Cell, but it should not be visible, only when the user scrolls down.

My Trys:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    float rowHeight = [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, rowHeight);
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTopanimated:NO];

}
```

Both did not work.

Any advice on my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: It is similar to Pull-To-Refresh, but instead of a refresh, the first cell should be visible.

Comment: How are you populating the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(t,l,b,r)];
```

this will shift your `tableView` whatever way you want, but you can definitely scroll back.

Answer (score 0):

Try your logic in the TableView Delegate methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } 
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //Your filters here
    } 
    else {
        //display the cell
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Also if you dont wish the first cell to be displayed just write

```
return nil; //for condition of indexpath.row == 0
```

And also adjust the height for the row in

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0 && isDisplayThisSection) {//first visible

        UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320, 25)] autorelease];

        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 10, 300, 25)]; 

        [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]];

        titleLabel.text = @"Temp Test";

        [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [headerView addSubview:titleLabel];

        [titleLabel release];

        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        return headerView;

    }
    return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] autorelease];

}
```

set value to 0

Hope this help!!

Comment: I want the first cell to be displayed, but only, if it is pulled out.

Answer (score -1):

Try your logic in the TableView Delegate methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } 
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //Your filters here
    } 
    else {
        //display the cell
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Also if you dont wish the first cell to be displayed just write

```
return ; //for condition of indexpath.row == 0
```

And also adjust the height for the row in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

set value to 0

And if you wish to implement like Pull_to_Refresh, you would better write your logic in

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: i think you didn't understand my problem correct. If you have WhatsApp, you can pull out a searchbar from top and i want the same mechanism.

Comment: Did you mean to add a search bar in top of your tableview?

Comment: Not a searchbar, a custom UITableViewCell

Comment: then you can use viewForHeaderInSection: method for section=0

please check my edited answer

Comment: But is it hidden, when i start my application?

Comment: Well you can hide/unhide it using a flag in this method